# Как пофиксить подзапрос?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Мне нужно посчитать количество колонок таблицы в которых количество непустых записей больше 2млрд(я не могу создать такую таблицу, поэтому там 3).
Я пробую делать это запросом, который делает каунт по названию, с названий колонок с таблиц, где в подзапросе я считаю количество непустых записей в таблице. Но подзапрос почему-то возвращает ошибку. Как его пофиксить.
Ошибка ниже.

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

```
SELECT count(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'users'
group by INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME 
having (
    select count_big(COLUMN_NAME)
    from users
    where COLUMN_NAME is not null )>3
```

Comment: А что за ошибка?

Comment: @gil9red Добавил описание ошибки

Comment: `count` и `count_big` считают только те значения, которые не равны null, если указано имя колонки. Так что проверку можно убрать.

Comment: Решили проблему? | В подзапросе вместо `COLUMN_NAME` должно быть имя колонки из таблицы `users`, не так-ли?